# Good set of problems in general topology

Tags: general-topology, book-recommendation

As an undergrad I am halfway through my first course on general topology and to increase my skills wanted to solve some problem. I want to know which books excercise would help me the most - Munkres topology or J.L.Kelley general topology ? Which one has more difficult ones ? Which one has wide range of problems ? This question is asked many time on this website but I am only concerned with these two books only!! So please don't close the question or recommend other books.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not choose both books, and pick what ever exercise interests you? Probably you find both textbooks online. Munkres for sure.

Comment: but still can you give me some knowledge beforehand?

Comment: Is the homework from your course too easy?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to recommend [MAT327: Big List](http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/biglist.pdf) - which is a large, constantly growing list of problems in general topology. The problems come (or are inspired) from various sources, as listed on the first page of the document. Thanks to *Ivan Khatchatourian* of the *Department of Mathematics, University of Toronto* for compiling this big, organized list of amazing problems.

The benefit of using this repository of problems is that it is a collection of "good" problems from several sources. You don't have to spend time filtering books to find "good" problems, Ivan has already done that for us! Moreover, the problems are **rated by difficulty**, which can be especially helpful for a beginner.